# IE 11 seems to have a lowered limit on .options[] - firefox works fine - IE <11 works fine

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
    function fillarray(arrname) {
       var list1 = document.FORM1.MASTERLIST;
       var list2 = document.getElementById(arrname);
       var rmax = list2.options.length;
       var lmax = list1.options.length;
       var partc = "";
       if (rmax != 0) {var setname = list2.options[list2.selectedIndex].text;}
       for (var loop1 = 0 ; loop1 < lmax ; loop1=loop1+1) {
          partc = list1.options[loop1].text;
          list2.options[loop1]=new Option( partc , partc );
       }
       if ((rmax != 0) && (setname != "")) {
          var si = inlist(list2,setname);
          list2.options[si-1].selected = true;
       }
       return;
    }​
```

My issue seems to be at the line "for (var loop1 = 0...."

Through testing, I've found 2995 is the highest loop1 will work with. Above that I wind up with no elements at all in my SELECT options.

I predefined a Master list of options - and when each of specific drop downs are selected, I copy the master list into that list - so I don't have to define each list with oodles of options when loading.

Everything worked fine, until W7 upgraded to IE11 - older versions of IE work without a problem. I haven't tested it on another OS platform other than W7 so I don't know if it's specific to IE11 on W7

Is there an upper limit or an upper total size limit to how many options[] can be in a list for IE11? or
is there a bug that anyone else has noticed this happening.

I just did an additional test, by limiting the size of each option description to 5 characters, and the full amount of options loaded - so it's not a limit on the number - it must be total length.

Rightnow - it's about 4500 entries at about 25 bytes each for both the value and the description so about 225k - I seem to have a problem around 150k of total length.

Added: This issue also seems to exist on Edge as well as IE 11 - and seems to be related to the onfocus and onblue event triggering. it seems like the onfocus is triggering the onblur which doesn't make sense, as there are no .focus in the focus routine or anything that would take focus away once someone clicks.  When you click - it takes about 5-10 seconds to run - like it's running a really long script - which is it bouncing back and forth from the focus and blue functions. Very odd. my Events are all inline, I may try to change this to use JQuery to add the events once the page loads.

Added:
OK - after much much debugging - I found where the problem is happening.
in the line "list2.options[loop1]=new Option( partc , partc );'" inside the function run by OnFocus, that is causing the OnBlur event to fire. - Seems to only happen in IE11 and Edge. Now I have to figure out if I can disable the onBlur event until after I load the array, then reenable it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have IE 11 right now, but a much simpler test case would be to create 3,000 options in a loop and append them to a select. 3,000 options seems practically unusable.

Comment: I just added - it's not the number of options, it seems it's the overall size. I changed the length of each option to be 5 characters, instead of the usually 25-35 characters - and it loaded all (around 4500). I agree, the size seems (is) excessive - but it was linked to a routine that would hone in when you typed characters - I've eliminated that section - so it's not that part of the code that's the issue.

Comment: In doing some debugging, it is loading the entire array, however, I think the issue I'm having is not specific to that routine - The HTML code is utilizing an onFocus to load the array, and an onBlur to move the selected item to another element and then clear the array. It seems like when the onFocus is firing, it runs the OnBlur right afterwards and never actuallys allows you select your choice.  Another odd thing is when I run this in Firefox, it takes a fraction of second to load the array, when IE loads the array, it takes about 4-5 seconds.

Comment: this is looking more like an issue with the onfocus/onblur events - which would explain why it's taking much longer for the array to load. In doing some searching, seems IE 11 has had some issues with those events, however, I haven't found any searches similar to my issues with them.

Comment: OK - now this is weird. My HITML element for the SELECT box had a size=1 - If I change the size 2 or higher - it works (events work as expected). If it's size =1 the events go haywire. For debugging purposes I created a text box and wrote to it (since I can't use alert). The very first line in my function writes to the text box, however, when the function is triggered by the OnFocus() event - it takes about 4 seconds before the function is actually executed?!? IE 11 only.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment not an answer, however the answer section allows posting of code so I'm using it instead.

The following works in all versions of IE back to IE 5, though until  IE9 the options don't display correctly. Your issue is possibly that the data source is not fully loading.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('sel0');
var base = 'This option has a long value to test things ';
for (var i=0; i<5000; i++) {
  sel.appendChild(new Option(base + i, base + i));
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="sel0" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
    <option value="first">first</option>
  </select>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: I'll have to test the above also just to see if that works - since the size is about the same, however, that gave me something else to check - since the Master list is built dynamically - now I'm wondering if maybe one of the descriptions may contain an invalid character.

Comment: Actually, it was somewhat of an answer - as it shows my problem wasn't with the size of the select array - so it was helpful though.